# Create Queue dynamically with different exchange types

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, kombu

I'm trying to write a method that creates new queues with arguments of an existing exchange name, new queue name and routing key. The exchange might be in different types (direct, fanout, topic).

Is there a way to make and bind the queue without knowing the exchange type?

```
def my_queue(self, exchange_name, queue_name, routing_key):
    with connection.acquire(block=True) as conn:
        ex = Exchange(exchange_name, type='topic')
        queue = Queue(name="my_queue", routing_key="my_key", exchange=ex)
        queue.maybe_bind(conn)
        queue.declare()
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Celery typically automatically creates queue for you, all you have to do is to call [add_consumer()](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#std:control-add_consumer) to subscribe (during runtime) one or more workers to the particular queue. As mentioned, if the queue does not exist, Celery will make it for you. Similarly, you may want to unsubscribe from the queue, in which case you call [cancel_consumer()](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues-canceling-consumers).

Comment: I need to make queue for a specific exchange, and add_consumer also requires exchange name and type (see the link you provided):
"If you need more control you can also specify the exchange, routing_key and even other options"

Comment: You do not have to specify the exchange at all. `add_consumer('new_queue', reply=True,            destination['celery1@domain.tld'])` works just fine.